# How to show SD Card image in Feed Dialog

Tags: android, facebook, sd-card, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

I am writing a program in which I am allowing user to post a message along with image on their [Friend & User] Wall, and i am using SD Card image to post, but whenever i see my Feed Dialog in place of my SD Card's image i am getting Google's Logo, because in link parameter i used www.google.com, so it's picking that image, see below:

[image]

I tried with some other web links, and found it is picking any image from that link....

So here my question, why i am not getting SD Card image there

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view,
            final int position, long id) {

        try {
            friendId = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getLong("uid");
            String name = jsonArray.getJSONObject(position).getString("name");
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.post_on_wall_title)
            .setMessage(
            String.format(getString(R.string.post_on_wall),
            name)).setPositiveButton(R.string.yes,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            try 
                    {
           String myPath  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
          .getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Facebook/flower1.jpg";

           File f = new File(myPath);
           FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);

            Log.d("onItemClick", "fis ::--" + fis);

            Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
            Log.d("onItemClick", "bi ::--" + bi);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Log.d("onItemClick", "baos ::--" + baos);
                bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
            data = baos.toByteArray();
                Log.d("onItemClick", "data ::--" + data);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
             e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("onCreate", "debug error  e = " + e.toString());
                                   }     

                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                params.putString("to", String.valueOf(friendId));
                    params.putString("caption", getString(R.string.app_name));
            params.putString("description", getString(R.string.app_desc));
            params.putString("link", "http://www.google.com");  
            params.putString("method", "photos.upload"); 
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);
                Log.d("onItemClick", "params.putByteArray ::--" + data);
            params.putString("name", getString(R.string.app_action));
                                                                FacebookUtility.facebook.dialog(FriendsList.this, "feed", 
                    params, (DialogListener) newPostDialogListener());
                                                        }

            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.no, null).show();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            showToast("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I have also given these **permission** in Manifest:

```
<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission 
    android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

hey why dont you try absolute path

```
String myPath = sdcardEnvironment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Pictures/Facebook/flower1.jpg";
```

Also check that you have provide Permission in manifest file for external read write

try this

Answer (score 0):

The feed dialog does not support uploading images, it only allows you to supply a url for the "picture" parameter.

See the full docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/